# Sometimes can't find the ble device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on the Android-Ble develop .
There is my problem:
When the Ble device was disconnect the program will call .startLeScan(callback) to find Ble device and reconnect .
But sometimes , the program tried to scan but it can't find any device.I guess it was caused by Ble protocol stack messed.
Am I right? And if Ble protocol stack messed , so what happening will make the  Ble protocol stack mess?
Can anybody give me some tips?Thanks.

---There is scan code:

```
private void startBLEScan() {
    if (isBLEScanStarted) {
        return; 
    }else {
        isBLEScanStarted = true;
    }
    if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
        boolean startResult = mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        System.out.println("BlueToothScan: startLeScan      "+startResult);
        startBLEScanTimeoutTimer(1000 * 60);   //When scan time reach 60s , stop scan and rescan after 5s.
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("BlueToothScan: adapter is null");
    }
}
```

---There is gatt callback .OnConnectionStateChange:

```
@Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
            int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                if(mBluetoothGatt != null){
                    mBluetoothGatt.close();
                    mBluetoothGatt = null;
                }
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What type of BLE device is that? Did you try to find it with another device when the connection is lost?

Comment: I have try to find it with another mobile, and can get a connection to the BLE device.Uh.. I am sorry ,I am not very understand about what type of BLE device is that...Meants where it made from or other?

Comment: No, like is it a fitness device? Most of these BLE devices turn off when they are not used for a prolonged period of time.

Comment: Yep,but when I lost connection for the BLE devices .I can't get any devices. I think if just the devices turn off  I can still get other's mac,,but it's not..So I guess some wrong step make the Ble protocol stack messed .

Comment: Post some code, we cannot help without that.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it's the same issues because this problem comes only since i update to Android 5.1. I can connect and bond devices to my Android, but when it comes to reconnection, the scan will not find any devices that are already bonded.

My code works great in Android 5.0 and the only changes for the Bluetooth low energy is the scan method. Now I must use the BluetoothScanner class and no more call the startLeScan method from the BluetoothAdapter class because it's deprecated.

The problem comes perhaps from the length of the packet because the advertisement name change when the device is bonded or not bonded. 
Another idea is that Google changes the security when it comes to connect an already bonded device, but normally it will not affect the discovery with a scan.